# unique two columns together in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, web, django-models

I'm working on a social network project and I need to make followers and followings for the users so i did it with another Model named `Follow`

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="followers", blank=False,null=False)
    following = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="followings",blank=False,null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.follower.username + " is following " + self.following.username
```

and now I'm gonna unique two columns together, for example somebody can't follow himself or if that record exists, don't record it again

how to make two records unique together

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman how to do make Conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for unique records you can add meta option [unique-together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/1.11/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    # YOUR CODE HERE

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("follower", "following"),)
```

for somebody can't follow himself

you can look on the [validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

Comment: and what about two records?!

Comment: did you read the link: [unique-together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/1.11/ref/models/options/#unique-together)? by using this option you can have only one record with "follower", "following"

Comment: yes and it was helpful for one of my questions but it won't work for not allowing someone follows himself!

Comment: I think this answer could be greatly improved if you quoted the most important part of the second link you provided.

Comment: many way for second link, i hope you try someone and can create new question if has any troubles.